# Change bar color according to the size of the bar R

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, geom-col

With ggplot I´ve made a histogram with some values. I want to change the color of the highest bar, so that it makes the plot more legible.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, 
       aes(as.Date(created_at), as.numeric(count))) +
  geom_col(fill = 'cornflowerblue') + 
  theme_minimal(base_size = 10) +
  xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL) + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y/%m/%d",date_breaks = "days",expand = c(0,0)) +  #El espaciado por días
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, vjust = 0.5))+#Cambiamos la posición del x 
  geom_text(aes(label = count, y = count+50), position = position_dodge(0.9),angle=90, vjust = 0.5,size=3)+
  ggplot2::theme(
    plot.title = ggplot2::element_text(face = "bold",colour = "black"))+
  ggplot2::labs(
    x = NULL, y = NULL, #Info en cada eje 
    title = "Tweets sobre el COVID-19 por día", #Texto 
    subtitle = ""
  )
```

Comment: Hi Adrian. That definitely sounds like the kind of problem we could help you with on Stack Overflow. If you show us your code by adding it to your question then I'm sure we could suggest the necessary modifications.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data(mtcars)

count(mtcars, cyl) %>%
  mutate(col=ifelse(n==max(n), "red","blue")) %>%  # Add this line,
  ggplot(aes(cyl, n, fill=as.factor(col))) +
    geom_col() +
    ylab("Frequency") +
    scale_fill_identity() +  # And this one to use the actual colours.
    theme_minimal()
```

[image]